# Can "amateur" be used as a predicative adjective to describe a person ("I am amateur at X")?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

In everyday usage, I would use the word *amateur* like this:

> (Noun) I am an amateur rock climber. (Adjective) I participate in amateur rock climbing.

It also sounds right for me to say the following:

> **(1)** (Adjective) I participate in, but am amateur at, rock climbing.

My question is whether the usage above is appropriate. In other words, using "amateur" in the form:

> I am amateur at [...]

[Oxford dictionary gives](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/amateur) the example sentence "it's all so amateur!" that seems to have a similar usage.

It uses "amateur" as an adjective modifying "it", so it doesn't seem like too much of a stretch to have "amateur" modify "I". Is that enough evidence to support it being used in the above way?

Comment: I think if you look in an actual dictionary you will get the answer to this question pretty handily. Try googling "amateur definition adjective" and then click on one of the links to a dictionary site, like Oxford Dictionaries or Merriam-Webster. Note that you may have to scroll down within a particular entry to get all the parts of speech.

Comment: Definitely not out of the question that I haven't looked close enough.

I just now went through Oxford, Merriam-Webster, and a few others. I couldn't find an examples that explicitly say "I am amateur at [...]". Maybe I'm asking the question incorrectly?

Comment: @1006a Though OP should certainly add dictionary references, I don't agree that this will resolve the question. 'It's all so amateur' sounds a lot less idiomatic to my ears than 'It's all so amateurish', even though dictionaries I've checked in class the adjectives as synonyms. I think this needs serious analysis. The premodifier usage of 'amateur' is possibly in the course of conversion from noun to adjective.  This could limit the number of idiomatic strings available. / 'I am **an** amateur at rock climbing' is also more idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The use of "amateur" as an adjective also seems to be better established when it refers to things rather than people: Oxford Dictionaries gives the example sentence "‘Some of the attempts were amateur and romantically inept", but the word "amateur" of course doesn't have the same meaning here as it would in CalendarJ's sentence.

Comment: I have never in my life heard "amateur" as a predicate adjective describing a person. You will get responses that fail to differentiate between noun and adjective. I for one am convinced that it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of the word and reading of the dictionary examples would say that it's not really correct to say you are "amateur at something". That said, I think the phrase is common enough it won't raise too many eyebrows. Personally, I would say "I'm learning to rock climb", if I'm indicating my skill level as "amateur". Really, the word should be amateurish when describing poor ability and that word has too much negative connotation. I would use "amateur", more typically, to indicate non-professional activities. But you could also talk about hobbies and pastimes.

For your example, if you want to use the word correctly, I would say:

> I'm an amateur rock-climber.

Rather than:

> I'm an amateur *at* rock climbing.

Comment: I'm an amateur story teller: I am an amateur at telling stories. I that not right? :)

Answer (score 1):

According to Etymonline and other dictionaries, [amateur](https://www.etymonline.com/word/amateur) is rooted in a French word meaning *lover of* (something). In your first example sentence, *amateur* is used as an adjective along with *rock*, to modify the noun, **climber**.

- I am a climber. (What kind of climber?)
- I am a rock climber. (Are you a professional rock climber?)
- No, I am an *amateur* rock **climber**.

Furthermore, a quick check of the NGrams for common usage of the word, shows that it isn't used as a predicative adjective:

[image: I am amateur]

Same result for "I am amateur at":

[image: I am amateur at]

But is commonly used in the way that has already been explained in the first answer given here (by Lowell Montgomery):

[image: I am an amateur]

"I am an amateur at" barely registers on the NGram, which suggests it's uncommon and probably not grammatically correct:

[image: I am an amateur at]

Comment: I am an amateur also is: I'm an amateur, not to mention, he, she, they, you and we.  This is one of those examples where you either know it or you don't. Ngrams simply does not work for everything, especially speech, and every written possibility.

Comment: Take at look at this dialogue in a book: https://books.google.com/books?id=DY1adEvMVRAC&pg=PT282&lpg=PT282&dq=%22He%27s+an+amateur+at%22&source=bl&ots=ZDM15w_9hi&sig=DnBtOJd9HbeQYTzMaU5v1MJgZTI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif1IzQ3LDaAhXtYN8KHQm5C2AQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=%22He's%20an%20amateur%20at%22&f=false

Comment: @Lambie ~ I understand, but there's no reason why my examples don't work to prove my point here. You don't have to run every pronoun through it, to get the idea.

Comment: @Lambie ~ I already conceded within my answer, that "I am an amateur at" is used sometimes. However, I don't consider your citation any example of fine literature. In fact, the use of the F-word makes it clear to me at least, that it is informal and slangy. It is also used within the dialogue of a presumably uneducated character.

Comment: There are quite a few relevant examples of 'were amateurs at' in competently written pieces [on the internet](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22were+amateurs+at%22&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ei=UUbNWr6XEMuFgAaHq57gBQ&start=10&sa=N&biw=1680&bih=908).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth ~ "I am an amateur at" (as relevant to the OP) has only one notable modern usage, and it's for punk song lyrics. https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&biw=1280&bih=590&ei=e1vNWvTSEYWGjwTL56DoAw&q=I+am+an+amateur+at&oq=I+am+an+amateur+at&gs_l=psy-ab.3...8335.8663.0.9161.3.3.0.0.0.0.85.227.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.wASdWo5U6L0 If we're going to admit slang, pretty much anything goes, and there's no point in asking if anything is proper grammar. Besides, I already covered that point with Lambie. It is already included in my original answer.

Comment: Very weak examples, by the way, on that google search. Another detective novel. Usage of the phrase out of context. Etc. You should be ashamed of yourself.

Comment: Labelling [the article by Caroline Moorhead of the Spectator](https://www.spectator.co.uk/2008/09/a-war-of-words/)  and [Mark Carroll's University of Illinois article](https://www.life.illinois.edu/entomology/newsletter/newsltr1999/linnaean.htm) as weak examples is what seems shameful to me.

Comment: Personally, I can't stand ngrams for these types of questions. That said, the number of hits there would increase a lot by using more pronouns. The fact is: to be an amateur at [verb]/to be an expert at [verb]/to be a whiz at [verb] cannot be proven to be "colloquial" at all. It is, however, a matter of opinion but is definitely not "not grammatical".

Comment: @Lambie ~ It is **to be an amateur at [noun]** (not verb). Amateur in the OP in this context is being used as an *adjective*, so it has to be a noun. Wikipedia says that **climbing** is an **activity**. An activity is a noun, a thing.  Also, "I can't stand ngrams": Thank you for having the courage and honesty to admit to your bias, much appreciated.

Comment: I also don't think to be an amateur at [noun] is colloquial. Not liking Ngrams for these types of questions is not a bias. It is a critical assessment based on the fact that ngrams cannot prove anything and not everything that is grammatical has already been written. Thank goodness for that. But, fear not, the AI people will do away with us writers soon enough.

Comment: @Lambie ~ Your point is well taken and I will give it serious consideration. Perhaps you and Edwin are right. It just sounds strange to me. And I realize I'm not terribly proficient with the Ngrams (it's embarrassing for me, really). And please remember that I **always** welcome anyone anytime to offer better answers than mine. I confess, I'm an amateur at English, :D

Comment: @Lambie ~ I can always spot AI writing, it really stinks. It's what I call *unreadable*.